# Regarding replace in string using .replace

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I have tried to use .replace in python to replace an empty list in a string but it is not working. Could anyone please tell me how?

```
x = ['check-[]|man', 'check-[]|king']

for y in x:
    if "[]" in y:
        y.replace("[]", "o")
        print(y)
```

The results gave me this despite using .replace:

```
check-[]|man
check-[]|king
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y.replace` returns a value.

You have to assign it back

```
y = y.replace("[]", "o")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign i back to variable `y`:

```
x = ['check-[]|man', 'check-[]|king']

for y in x:
    if "[]" in y:
        y=y.replace("[]", "o")
        print(y)
```

Output:

```
check-o|man
check-o|king
```